# Setting value in variable provided while creating paypal buy button

Tags: paypal

I have this paypal buttom generated to buy.The scripts contains some variable whose values are already provided but i want to provide the value to variables dynamically.

This is the buy button generated.

```
    <script
data-callback="http://sajilobazar.com" 
data-tax="3"
data-shipping="1" 
data-currency="USD" 
data-amount="45" 
data-quantity="1" 
data-name="helo" 
data-button="buynow" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=*****@yahoo.com" async="async">
</script>
```

As seen in the above code the variables like data-tax are pre populated.I want to provide my own value.

This is what i tried

```
var x= "3";
data-tax=x
```

But it won't work.Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-tax-editable which makes tax editable and enter a value to pass the dynamic tax variable.

Eg:

```
<script
data-callback="http://sajilobazar.com" 
data-tax-editable="3"
data-shipping="1" 
data-currency="USD" 
data-amount="45" 
data-quantity="1" 
data-name="helo" 
data-button="buynow" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=*****@yahoo.com" async="async">
</script>
```

But, alternatively you to use Button manager API to create dynamic buttons via [BMCreateButton](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) API call.